# Using Arrays in PostgreSQL 'where'-statement

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL Database structure consisting of three tables

- **separabilities** contains combinations of data bands in int arrays of ids and some more columns that are not relevant here
- **data_bands** contains the information to assign the ids in the arrays from 'separabilities' to actual files and  image bands
- **thematic_classes** contains information about the classes used in 'separabilities' (not that import for my question)

Table Definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE separabilities (
 data_bands integer[] NOT NULL,
 thematic_class1 integer NOT NULL,
 thematic_class2 integer NOT NULL,
 jm_dist double precision NOT NULL )

CREATE TABLE thematic_classes (
 id integer NOT NULL,
 file_name text NOT NULL )

CREATE TABLE data_bands (
 id integer NOT NULL,
 file_name text NOT NULL,
 band integer NOT NULL )
```

What I want is a Query that gives me the average separabilities grouped by data_bands and an array with the actual file names and bands corresponding to elements of the data_bands array in separabilities.

Without the connection to the file names the query works and looks like that:

```
select 
    sep.data_bands, 
    sum(sep.jm_dist)/count(sep.data_bands) as avarage_jm_dist 
from separabilities as sep 
group by sep.data_bands 
order by avarage_jm_dist
```

Example row of the result:
**{10,11} ; 0,7654**

What I need is:
**{10,11} ; {filename1:bandnumber, filename2:bandnumber}; 0,7654**

Comment: You'd have a better chance for an answer if you gave the table definitions in the form: `create table (...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1. Unnest `data_bands`, add `row_number` to `avarage_jm_dist` to distinguish consecutive `sep` entries:

```
    select 
        unnest(sep.data_bands) as bands, 
        array[sep.jm_dist/array_length(sep.data_bands, 1),
            row_number() over (order by sep.jm_dist)] as avarage_jm_dist
    from separabilities as sep
```

Step 2. Join `data_bands` according to unnested `bands` and aggregate results into arrays grouping by `avarage_jm_dist`

```
select 
    array_agg(sub.bands) as bands, 
    array_agg(b.file_name|| ' : '|| b.band) as file_names, 
    avarage_jm_dist[1]
from (
    select 
        unnest(sep.data_bands) as bands, 
        array[sep.jm_dist/array_length(sep.data_bands, 1),
            row_number() over (order by sep.jm_dist)] as avarage_jm_dist
    from separabilities as sep
    ) sub
join data_bands b on b.id = bands
group by avarage_jm_dist
order by avarage_jm_dist
```

Note 1. I have changed incorrect

```
sum(sep.jm_dist)/count(sep.data_bands)
```

to

```
sep.jm_dist/array_length(sep.data_bands, 1)
```

as the first expression always gives `sep.jm_dist`.

Note 2. `row_number` was added in case there are two (or more) rows in `separabilities` with the same `avarage_jm_dist`.